# multi level association and filter in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, model-associations, cakephp-3.2

I'm new to stackoverflow and this is my first question.
Please pardon me for any errors in question.

I'm working in CakePHP 3.2

I have `categories`, `products`, `seller_products` table and their association is like 
**CategoriesTable.php**

```
$this->hasMany('Products', [
   'foreignKey' => 'category_id'
]);
```

**ProductsTable.php**

```
$this->belongsTo('Categories', [
     'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
     'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
$this->hasMany('SellerProducts', [
    'foreignKey' => 'product_id'
]);
```

**SellerProducts.php**

```
$this->belongsTo('Products', [
    'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

**Table Association**

`products` table has `category_id` as foreign key referencing `categories` table and `seller_products` has `product_id` as foreign key referencing `products` table

`seller_products` has column `stock`.

**What I want to do is to select all categories containing associated products whose stock in seller_products is > 0**

This is what I have done

```
$pros1 = $this->Products->Categories->find()
  ->where([
     'Products.SellerProducts.stock >' => 0
  ])
  ->contain([
     'Products.SellerProducts', 'Subcategories', 'ProductTypes'
  ]);
```

but it is giving error as

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Products.SellerProducts.stock' in 'where clause'
```